# Windows Forms ,выбивает ошибку Значение не может быть неопределенным. Имя параметра item

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

Мне нужно чтобы в 1 листбокс выводилось имя студента а во второй листбокс его оценку , считываю из файла в котором уже было записано string и int , не могу понять в чём дело.

```
    panel2->Visible = true;
    FILE *pf;
    String ^name;
    int mark;
    pf = fopen("marks.txt", "r");
    if (pf == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Error");
    }
    else 
    {
        while (!EOF)
        {
            fscanf(pf, "%s%d", name, &mark);
        }
        fclose(pf);
        listBox1->Items->Add(name);
        if (ifPressedTest == true)
        {
            listBox2->Items->Add(mark.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `String ^name` - управляемый (managed) тип платформы .NET. Его **нельзя** использовать в неуправляемом (unmanaged) коде, в функции `fscanf`. Переписывайте полностью.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , а есть какая-нибудь замена fscanf тогда?

Comment: Изначально вы поставили метку C++. Но C++ в вашем коде нет. Совсем нет! Есть C++/CLI (это, собственно, всё относящееся к WinForms) и C (в частности, `FILE`, `fopen`, `fscanf`). Вы на каком языке пишете? Определитесь! Какой язык учите?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , Вообще , по идее C++ , просто учусь в университете и , возможно , у нас какие-то не те методы преподавания : нам просто сказали делать проект windowsforms , здесь могут встречаться "принципы ООП"(Я не знаю что это такое) ну и код в большем случае будет на C++(или по крайней мере похож на C++ по вашим словам) , а я видимо по незнанию начал использовать функции C, вообще я так понял у нас они  комбинируются .как-то так

Answer (score 0):

```
panel2->Visible = true;
try {
    StreamReader *reader = new StreamReader("marks.txt");
    do
    {
        String ^line = reader->ReadLine();
        String ^name = line.split(" ")[0];
        String ^mark = line.split(" ")[1];
        listBox1->Items->Add(name);
        if (ifPressedTest == true)
        {
            listBox2->Items->Add(mark);
        }
    } while(reader->Peek() != -1);
} catch (System::Exception *e) {
    MessageBox::Show("Error");
}
```

Можно вот так сделать.
Под рукой нет среды для Visual C++, поэтому могут быть ошибки, писал в блокноте.